# Scala support in listings package

Tags: listings

As far as I know, the Scala programming language is not supported
by the listings package.
Is an implementation under way? Will it be included in the standard
listings distribution?

Comment: Once I had the same problem with another programming language. I defined it myself and send the result to the listings-maintainer. In the next release it was added. When you look to [lstdrvrs.dtx](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx) you can find a lot of authors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Shamelessly pinched from [this site](http://tihlde.org/~eivindw/latex-listings-for-scala/), the following provides a Scala language definition for `listings`. Simply place it in your preamble, and use listings in the normal way.

```
% "define" Scala
\lstdefinelanguage{scala}{
  morekeywords={abstract,case,catch,class,def,%
    do,else,extends,false,final,finally,%
    for,if,implicit,import,match,mixin,%
    new,null,object,override,package,%
    private,protected,requires,return,sealed,%
    super,this,throw,trait,true,try,%
    type,val,var,while,with,yield},
  otherkeywords={=>,<-,<\%,<:,>:,\#,@},
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"""
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot of keywords are missing, though. Like Unit, Boolean, Int... Other than that, thanks for the TeX code. :)