# Unable to define scala language with listings

Tags: listings, color

I'm using the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47175/scala-support-in-listings-package) for scala support, but this fails to properly color the scala code, and throws a number of errors when processing lstset - `% ! Package keyval Error:   breakatwhitespace undefined.` Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with this simple example?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{listings}

% "define" Scala
\lstdefinelanguage{scala}{
  morekeywords={abstract,case,catch,class,def,%
    do,else,extends,false,final,finally,%
    for,if,implicit,import,match,mixin,%
    new,null,object,override,package,%
    private,protected,requires,return,sealed,%
    super,this,throw,trait,true,try,%
    type,val,var,while,with,yield},
  otherkeywords={=>,<-,<\%,<:,>:,\#,@},
  sensitive=true,
  morecomment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"""
}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=scala,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true
  tabsize=3
}
% A number of keyval errors occur here - basically 
% nothing in lstset is recognized. Errors look like:
% ! Package keyval Error:   breakatwhitespace undefined.

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
object Test {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      var a = 0;
      // for loop execution with a range
      for( a <- 1 to 10){
         println( "Value of a: " + a );
      }
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: After adding in `\listfiles`, here's the file list I see

```
 *File List*
IEEEtran.cls    2007/03/05 V1.7a by Michael Shell
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
  xspace.sty    2009/10/20 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
  epsfig.sty    1999/02/16 v1.7a (e)psfig emulation (SPQR)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
    cite.sty    2010/09/10  v 5.3
fancybox.sty    2010/05/15 1.4
listings.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2007/02/22 1.4 listings configuration
   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
lstlang1.sty    2004/09/05 1.3 listings language file
lstlang1.sty    2004/09/05 1.3 listings language file
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
  ot1pcr.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pcr.
sections/introduction.tex
sections/background.tex
sections/challenges.tex
sections/solution.tex
figures/vnc-overview.pdf
sections/results.tex
  omsptm.fd
figures/client-heap.png
figures/master-heap.png
sections/relatedwork.tex
sections/conclusion.tex
   clasp.bbl
```

Comment: This compiles fine for me (with updated TeXLive2014). Must be some issue related to an out of date package.  I'd suggest adding `\listfiles` just _before_ `\begin{document}` and posting the versions of all the packages here and we can compare.

Comment: Added, thanks for looking! If it matters, I'm using `latexmk -pdf` to compile because I'm a Latex compilation noob and need to focus on my dissertation :-P

Comment: I meant add `\listfiles` to the MWE above, _not_ you full doc as then many other packages are being added.  Yep, your packages are way out of date: I have `keyval.sty 2014/05/08 v1.15`, `listings.sty    2014/09/06`.  I'd recommend you use an update distribution rather than try to patch one package at a time.

Comment: Ah yea that makes sense, my bad. Upgrading fixed the issues, works fine now. If you'll post that as an answer I'll accept to mark this as closed

Comment: Ping @PeterGrill - in case you didn't see my comment above, this is just a note to make this an answer within next few days if you want the points

Comment: Thanks, but I think @Jubobs answer is better than what I would have written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by Peter in his comments, your TeX distribution seems badly out of date. Time to blow the rust off it, and fire up your package manager.

Also, you're missing a comma after `breakatwhitespace=true`.

Besides, since October 2013, the `listings` package comes with a language definition for Scala (in the [`lstdvrs.dtx` file](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx)). If you update your TeX distribution, you shouldn't have to redefine that language from scratch in your `.tex` file in order to use it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstdefinestyle{myScalastyle}{
  frame=tb,
  language=scala,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=myScalastyle]
object Test {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      var a = 0;
      // for loop execution with a range
      for( a <- 1 to 10){
         println( "Value of a: " + a );
      }
   }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had to run `sudo tlmgr update --all` to get the latest, MacTex 2014 was outdated. I think it's only fair to give Peter the answer credit, but if he doesn't answer within the next few days I'll mark this as accepted

Comment: Leave Peter an "@" comment below your question to ask him to post an answer.

Comment: Good point, done